# What does this German sentence with Angeber und auf die Pauke hauen mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I have the following sentence that I cannot decipher:

> Der Angeber soll man nicht so auf die Pauke hauen!

I do understand each word but together it somehow doesn't make sense.

**Angeber**: Verräter oder Wichtigtuer (nach duden.de)

**auf die Pauke hauen**: 1. kräftig feiern 2. angeben; sich lautstark bemerkbar machen; seine Meinung lautstark kundtun; laut aufbegehren (nach redensarten-index.de)

Shouldn't it be *dem Angeber* or *den Angebern* or even *als Angeber* then the third meaning of the *auf die Pauke hauen* would fit? I don't get it why genitiv is used here.

*(The sentence comes from the book: deutsch üben - Schwirige Wörter - the exercise was to fill in the AUF so the rest should be correct.)*

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you please check: is it really "man"? Or "mal"?

Comment: Oh man... I've been sitting on this sentence for the last 50 min and didn't see it should have been _mal_  \*verlegen\*. With _mal_ it's obvious ;-)

Comment: Did you misread? The word *man* exists as a regional variant of *mal* in this sense.

Comment: But the sentence works with both versions, see Carstens answer. I'd guess that it's a regional thing if you use "mal" (-> south) or "man" (-> north).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the second meaning of _man_ and honestly I didn't expect it would have another one. Now all catches in this sentence seem to be solved ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the word "man". It is just used for emphasis and has no particular meaning. Also, it is regional, I think. If you omit the word, the meaning will become clear.

> Der Angeber soll nicht so auf die Pauke hauen!

"Angeber" is used in the second sense that the Duden lists. Indeed, I think that I have never encountered the word used in the first sense.

Comment: You're right. Without man/mal the sentence is clear. I was so focussed on the Pauke und hauen (new in this exercise) that I didn't think of the rest of the sentence too much. Thank you.